# Adicionar imageview e quebrar linha

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho um conjunto de imagem na minha pasta `assets`, porem a quantidade vai sempre ficar mudando, então preciso adicionar uma `ImageView` via código.

Porem como eu não sei a quantidade, não sei quando elas iriam sair da janela. Preciso verificar se a imagem iria ficar fora da janela e "quebrar uma linha", e continuar colocando as `ImageView`.

Comment: Por que não usa uma ListView?

Comment: Mas como eu iria adicionar X imagens em cada item da lista, sendo que X não é um número exato, vai depender do tamanho da resolução do aparelho.
X seria a quantidade de imagem que o aparelho iria suportar na horizontal.

Comment: Penso que agora entendi: quer colocar um número `x` de imagens na horizontal sendo que esse número depende da resolução, as restantes imagens passam para a linha seguinte. Certo? Use então uma GridView

Comment: Vou dar uma lida sobre gridview ainda não usei ele, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz isso utilizando 3 `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/l1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/l2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/l3"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Mais ai eu dividi só em 3 a tela do celular , se o celular for maior a imagem fica maior se a tela for menor.Do jeito que está o l1,l2,l3 ele divide a tela em 3 cada `LinearLayout` fica do mesmo tamanho do outro. Eu coloquei as imagens por linha de codigo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]